# Jquery multiple div slide toggle inside ul li

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs inside ul li

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="flip" class="manage-image-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="/files/images/icns/settings-1.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>TEST</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="flip" class="manage-image-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="/files/images/icns/settings-1.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>TEST</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="flip" class="manage-image-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="/files/images/icns/settings-1.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h4>TEST</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Im using this for the script for the slide toggle

```
$('#panel').hide();
$("#flip").click(function () {
    $(this).next("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

it only toggles on the first `<li>` but not on the rest of the `<li>`. Dont know what i'm doing wrong. The  `$(this).next("#panel").slideToggle("slow");` doesn't seem to be working.

i have added the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ubea3p0/) link

Comment: having multiple of the same Id does NOT work, lose that habbit

Comment: You have three elements with the same id. In this case you should use classes instead of ids, because the id must be unique on the DOM to avoid extrange behaviours.

Comment: 1. you have multiple elements with the same id. 2. In your html there is no element with id panel.

Answer (score 2):

- dont use same ID for more than 1 divs. that violates w3c standard
- use class for your jquery selector for the `click()`
- i dont see `id="panel"` in your html. use class instead

```js
$('.panel').hide();
$(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.manage-account-master {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.manage-account-master-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

.manage-account-master-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

.manage-account-1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.manage-account-2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.manage-account-3 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.manage-account-4 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.manage-account-inner {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.manage-account-inner-1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.manage-account-inner-2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    h4 {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    ul {
        display: block;
    }
}

.rig {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.rig li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.manage-image-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.manage-image-container img {
    width: 80px !important;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 40;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#panel,
#flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#panel {
    background: aliceblue;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="manage-account-master">
    <div class="manage-account-inner">
        <div class="manage-account-inner-1">
            <div class="manage-account-inner-2">
                <ul class="rig">
                    <li>
                        <div class="flip manage-image-container">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="https://creativecommons.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/search.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <h4>Cats</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            Menus
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="flip manage-image-container">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Very_Basic//upload_21600.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <h4>Dogs</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            Menus
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="flip manage-image-container">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/09/house-icon-vector.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <h4>Horses</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            Menus
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="flip manage-image-container">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ez8pDFoxU2ZqDmyfeIjIba6dWisd8MY_6choHhZNpO0WwLhICu0v0s5eV2WHOhuhKw=w170" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <h4>Settings</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel">
                            Menus
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ubea3p0/3/).